# What is the best way to fire an event from an AngularJS directive for an AJAX file upload?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a page to track a pool league I am in.  Currenly I hard-code the HTML and link to files that are part of the project for the weekly stats PDF I get from the league and a scanned copy of the score sheet from the last week.  I was able to get a drag-and-drop file upload working but I want to make the component as re-usable as possible.

To that end I created a directive 'dropFile' that you set to the URL where the file upload gets posted to.  The idea is that the file upload routine will call a function specified in another attribute, 'on-file-uploaded' and pass it the `file`, which is the original dropped file object with attributes added for responseText, completed flag and error flag.  The file upload will store the file in a database and return JSON with the ID, an MD5 hash and other properties.  The `week` of pool will store the hashes for those files and display links to an MVC action that will return the file from the database.  Here's how I envision the HTML looking:

```
<div drop-file="/fileupload"
    on-file-uploaded="gotStats"
    ng-hide="week.statsHash">
    DROP STATS
</div>
<div ng-show="week.statsHash">
    <a href="/files/{{week.statsHash}}">Stats</a>
</div>

<div drop-file="/fileupload" 
    on-file-uploaded="gotScores"
    ng-hide="week.scoresHash">
    DROP SCORES
</div>
<div ng-show="week.scoresHash">
    <a href="/files/{{week.scoresHash}}">Scores</a>
</div>
```

This way I have to create two methods on my controller, `gotStats` and `gotScores`, that will be called and that will update the `statsHash` and `scoresHash`.  Error checking is omitted for simplicity here:

```
$scope.gotStats = function(file) {
    var response = JSON.parse(file.responseText);
    $scope.week.statsHash = response.hash;
};

$scope.gotScores = function(file) {
    var response = JSON.parse(file.responseText);
    $scope.week.scoresHash = response.hash;
};
```

Is this the best way to accomplish what I want?  I could emit a `fileUploaded` event from the directive and that would allow me to pass the file and other arguments and give access to the directive's scope, right?  It seems a little hinky just giving a function name for `on-file-uploaded`, is there a better way?  I use this as part of my isolated scope:

```
scope: {
    allowMultiple: "=",
    uploadCompleteMethod: "&onFileUploaded"
},
```

And call it like this:

```
var func = scope.uploadCompleteMethod();
if (func)
    func(file);
```

Also since I have an isolated scope, it appears I can't use `ng-hide` to hide the drop box when the scores have finished uploading...

[(***fiddle***)](http://jsfiddle.net/jgoemat/f7St4/)

I like the directive notion because you can just throw it on an element to accept drag-and-drop file uploading and you can then use HTML inside the element to style it and show the upload progress, but is there a better way?

Comment: can wire both controller and directive to a service to share data and update that service when data comes back from upload

Comment: can you give an example?  how do they share data for two separate files in the same outer scope?

Comment: if data is an object in service and you set a variable in many places equal to that service object it gets shared by prototypical inheritance. `var newObj=oldObj` doesn't make a copy, just a refrence so changing either will change the other...they are the same object

Comment: Here's a very basic example demo http://plnkr.co/edit/NMfDVCAJsv0PHadqgjc2?p=preview

Comment: That's the opposite of what I want.  I need two unique instances because I'm uploading two separate files.  [`this fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/jgoemat/jSpuX/2/) shows more what I want the end result to look like.

Comment: still not clear what problem you are having.

Comment: Like in the fiddle in my comment above, I will need a controller on the `ng-repeat` element because all I can pass to the `onFileUploaded` attribute is a function name and I don't know what week it is for.  I thought there might be a better way but I can't think of it.  I could pass the scope and element as additional arguments to the specified function but that seems inelegant.

Comment: sorry... having hard time following this whole thread